# python matplotlib pie chart unexpected values

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, pie-chart

I am learning using matplotlib visualizations and was doing a simple pie chart. I am wondering why when I plot this, the percentages are as follow:

[image: image plot]

I was expecting it to show 40% frogs and 50% hogs...

Do I need to normalize or something?

```
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs'

sizes = [40,50]
#explode = (0, 0.1, 0, 0)  # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Hogs')

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes,labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.

plt.show()
```

Comment: 40/90 = 44.4%.... 50/90 = 55.6%

Answer (score 1):

As BigBen indicated in his comment, pie charts use 100% total. Your values of 50 and 40 do not add up to 100, so it takes them as total counts, not percent, and therefore assumes the grand total of frogs and hogs to be 90, not 100.

Answer (score 1):

[`pie`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html) has a parameter `normalize`:

> `normalize`: `None` or bool, default: `None`
>
> When `True`, always make a full pie by normalizing x so that `sum(x) == 1`. `False` makes a partial pie if `sum(x) <= 1` and raises a ValueError for `sum(x) > 1`.
>
> When `None`, defaults to `True` if `sum(x) >= 1` and `False` if `sum(x) < 1`.

In the future, the default will always be `True`, so `False` needs to be set explicitly.

To have some percentages, the values can be divided by `100`, and a partial pie will be drawn:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(6, 2))

labels = ['Frogs', 'Hogs']
sizes = [40, 50]
ax1.pie([s / 100 for s in sizes], normalize=False, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
ax1.axis('equal')
ax1.set_title('40% frogs, 50% hogs')

ax2.pie([0.15], normalize=False, labels=['Frogs'], autopct='%1.0f%%')
ax2.axis('equal')
ax2.set_title('15% frogs')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: partial pies]